# Why is my UltraGridRow ListObject null after loading a serialized DisplayLayout

Tags: .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am using an Infragistics UltraGrid in my WinForms application. Infragistics `v13.1`.

I have recently added code to save grid layouts in a binary serialized format and load them back using the `CopyFrom` method on the `DisplayLayout` object.

While I load one of these saved layouts, the grid is modified appropriately and data still shows correctly in the grid, but any time I ask for a `ListObject` on a row, it returns null.  The datasource for the grid is a `BindingSource` whose `DataSource` is a `BindingList` (this data is not changed when the layout is loaded).

Save:

```
Dim MS As New IO.MemoryStream()
ugl.Save(MS, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.All)
Return MS.ToArray()
```

Load:

```
Private Function ConvertToUltraGridLayout(data As Byte()) As UltraGridLayout
    Dim ugl As New UltraGridLayout()
    Dim MS As New IO.MemoryStream(data)
    MS.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    ugl.Load(MS, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.PropertyCategories.All)
    Return ugl
End Function

dgrServices.DisplayLayout.CopyFrom(ConvertToUltraGridLayout(lOption.Layout))
```

What do I need to do to get the `ListObject` to be non-null?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to understand the problem if some code were provided. Usually Save/Load methods of the UltraGrid.DisplayLayout are using to save/restore the UltraGrid layout. The code example is included to the Infragistics Windows Forms Samples Explorer and titled “Loading and Saving Layouts”.

Comment: I have updated to add the code example

Comment: I also tried using the `Load` method on the grid's already instantiated `DisplayLayout`, instead of the `CopyFrom` method, and it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I was using to get the row ListObject was `dgrServices.Rows`.  The reason `DisplayLayout` that I am loading has a Group By applied.  This causes the rows hierarchy to change so that it can put the special group header rows.  These, correctly, have no `ListObject`.

Now I just need to figure out the easiest way to get the databound rows in the grid and skip over these special group by header rows.

http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase~Rows.html